# Running Spring application with exec-maven-plugin

Tags: java, maven, exec-maven-plugin

I need to run a Spring based webservice using exec-maven-plugin. Whole setup is running fine using `exec:java` with below configuration :

```xml
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<configuration>
    <goal>java</goal>
    <mainClass>com.markit.valuations.common.spring.SpringMain</mainClass>
    <arguments>
        <argument>applicationContext-valuations-webapp.xml</argument>
    </arguments>
    <systemProperties combine.children="append">
        <systemProperty>
            ..........
            ..........
        </systemProperty>
    </systemProperties>
</configuration>
```

Now i want to do some performance analysis, so need to connect process to Profiler. So i want to use `exec:exec` to run the Spring application. I have made below changes to configuration but it gives error as it is not able to find `applicationContext-valuations-webapp.xml` . Can someone please advise on how to fix below configuration

```xml
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<configuration>
    <goal>exec</goal>
    <executable>java</executable>
    <mainClass>com.markit.valuations.common.spring.SpringMain</mainClass>
    <arguments>
        <argument>applicationContext-valuations-webapp.xml</argument>
    </arguments>
    <systemProperties combine.children="append">
        <systemProperty>
            .....
            .....
        </systemProperty>
    </systemProperties>
</configuration>
```